# MVC5 controller (POST) being called twice (once a week)

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a C# WebApp MVC5. Everything usually works perfectly, users create invoices every minute, there are 10 users making invoices concurrently in different locations and different machines.
The issue happens once a week.

In the logs, I can see the post is called twice at the same time by the same user, I see some network lag on the client-side when this happens, but I'm not able to reproduce it, even using the network utility of chrome DevTools to simulate network lag.

Of course, I can add some business validation before persisting the data into the database in order to avoid duplicate data, but that's not the real issue.

I've read on the internet it would be because IIS Http2 is enabled and should be disabled, so I've done that a couple of weeks ago, but the error is still occurring.

This is not an issue of an "unintentional double click on a button", I'm pretty sure is not because I make sure to disable the button once it is clicked and enabled back once the server returns a response.

See the logs: the first one takes 9002ms to completes while the second one takes 444ms. That's the network lag I've identified so far because this post usually takes less than a second to completes.

```
2021-09-22 16:21:41 167.86.95.177 POST /Sales/Invoices/Save - 443 jnamicela 45.225.105.89 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/93.0.4577.82+Safari/537.36 https://xpertdynamics.com/Home/Index 200 0 1236 9002
2021-09-22 16:21:41 167.86.95.177 POST /Sales/Invoices/Save - 443 jnamicela 45.225.105.89 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/93.0.4577.82+Safari/537.36 https://xpertdynamics.com/Home/Index 200 0 0 444
```

Comment: Even using chrome devtools to simulate network lag, it cannot be reproduced. So it is a random problem. Fortunately, the problem did not cause any abnormalities. Even if the call is repeated, the status code of the request in the log is 200. If you can narrow down the time frame of the problem, you may be able to monitor the application and IIS during this time period.

Answer (score 1):

It's solved. It was an issue on client-side. Basically they have unstable internet connection. When they click on the 'save' button and in the middle of the process they unspecteclly lose internet connection, the jquery.post will go directly to the post.fail, but the request was successfully sent to the server, it is just the browser that doesn't know it because internet connection was lost. So the user clicks on the 'save' button once again.
I just included a validation step before calling jquery.post. It is: check for internet connection using `navigator.onLine`, if yes, then check for the user session is still alive. if(true && true) then call jquery.post.
I've been monitoring since 3 weeks ago, and the error never happened again.